# Adding images to JavaScript image viewer without <a> or <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, imageview

SHORT VERSION

Can anyone offer me a JS image viewer which supports mechanism of passing image array on construction?

LONGER VERSION

I'm using Colorbox to view some images on a page.

The situation I desire is:

- I add an image to viewer from `<a>` tag on a thumbnail (using class name, for example)
- I add more images passing image hrefs to viewer object (thumbnails of these images aren't shown)
- When I click on my first (and only) thumbnail, a viewer opens with big version of thumbnail PLUS added images via viewer object.

The situation I got:
 - I put empty `<a>` tags (which I also make invisible in CSS) pointing to additional images I want to add (which don't have thumbnails).

Can anyone offer me a JS image viewer which supports such mechanism of passing image array on construction?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

In Colorbox, you create groups of things using the `rel` option. For example:

`$('.thumbnail').colorbox({rel: 'colorboxImg'})`

The above code means that when you click something with a class of `thumbnail`, the image viewer will open up and load all of the items that have a class of `colorboxImg`.

So, the "situation you got" (as you put it) is pretty close. Add a bunch of your hidden `<a>` tags and make sure the `href`s point to the right images. Give those `<a>` tags a class of `colorboxImg` (or whatever you decide to name your group) and you're done. Keep in mind that the `.thumbnail` also needs to have a class of `colorboxImg`.

Let me know if you have any other cases you need to satisfy and we can edit this answer.